# Adding new vectors to a numpy ndarray

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to do a project and I want to save a set of vectors into a numpy array.

I want to have a nd array like this:

```
[[[  2.52416655e+05  -3.39300988e+05  -1.47104728e+05]
  [  7.62810170e-02   4.71563079e-02   2.04445954e-02]]

 [[ -8.30154058e+10   1.11596039e+11   4.83823596e+10]
  [ -2.50869296e+04  -1.54980220e+04  -6.72001994e+03]]

 [[ -8.33917881e+10   1.11616209e+11   4.84208579e+10]
  [ -2.52465548e+04  -1.64620901e+04  -7.06724029e+03]]]
```

by having a single array like this in the beginning:

```
[[  2.52416655e+05  -3.39300988e+05  -1.47104728e+05]
 [ -8.30154058e+10   1.11596039e+11   4.83823596e+10]
 [ -8.33917881e+10   1.11616209e+11   4.84208579e+10]]
```

Through each iteration of my algorithm I will add a new set of vector to this array. After the first iteration the array will be like the nd array I showed in the first part.

Are there any numpy method that enables me to do that? Please let me know if there are any better way of doing this. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: So, to understand your question, you mean you want a means to store the array in your second part of the question to the array in the first part?

Comment: If the first is `x` with shape (3,2,3). The second is `x[:,0,:]` with shape (3,3).

Comment: @Jeremy, Sorry about making the question confusing. Basically the second part is what I have in the beginning, and I want to add a new set of array to it and make it like the first part.

Comment: Are you adding an array of the same size?  Have you looked at `np.stack`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With 2 (or more) identically shaped arrays you can join them on many axes, including the existing horizontal or vertical.  But `np.array` joins them on a new axis 'at the start':

```
In [429]: A = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
In [430]: B = np.arange(9,18).reshape(3,3)
In [431]: np.array([A,B])   # (2,3,3) array
Out[431]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17]]])
```

The result is the same as though I'd typed in a triple nested list.  `np.stack` is a newish version of `np.concatenate` than can do the same, or can join on another new axis.  I think `axis=1` does what you want:

```
In [432]: np.stack([A,B], axis=1)   # a (3,2,3) array
Out[432]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 9, 10, 11]],

       [[ 3,  4,  5],
        [12, 13, 14]],

       [[ 6,  7,  8],
        [15, 16, 17]]])
In [433]: _[:,0,:]      # selecting from the 2nd axis to get A
Out[433]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
```

Play around with `np.concatenate` and its derivatives.

Oh, and if you need to join a large number of arrays like this, it is better to collect them in a list `e.g.`[A, B, C, D,...]`and apply the`stack` just once.  List append is better for iterative use.

Some arrangements require further manipulation with transpose or axis swapping.  But I don't think that's needed here.

Answer (score 0):

If `X` is your array, you can do the following

```
np.vstack([x[0] for x in X]) # loop and get first element
```

or

```
np.vstack(X)[0::2] # get even rows
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you start from array a:

```
a
Out[891]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
```

And you want to append array b:

```
b
Out[892]: 
array([[ 9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17]])
```

You can merge them together to your final array 'final' using np.r_ and then reshape.

```
final = np.r_[a,b]

final.reshape((3,-1,3),order='F')
Out[898]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 9, 10, 11]],

       [[ 3,  4,  5],
        [12, 13, 14]],

       [[ 6,  7,  8],
        [15, 16, 17]]])
```

When you append another array c, you can do the same:

```
c
Out[899]: 
array([[18, 19, 20],
       [21, 22, 23],
       [24, 25, 26]])

final = np.r_[final,c]

final.reshape((3,-1,3),order='F')
Out[901]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 9, 10, 11],
        [18, 19, 20]],

       [[ 3,  4,  5],
        [12, 13, 14],
        [21, 22, 23]],

       [[ 6,  7,  8],
        [15, 16, 17],
        [24, 25, 26]]])
```

Comment: With np.stack you don't need order F